# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo. Me genera un error al ejecutar el API de Paypal para Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, api, android-intent, paypal

Estoy trabajando un proyecto de integración del API de Paypal en Android Studio, pero al hacer el Intent de la actividad me genera el siguiente error:

```
Process: com.example.vivotelecom, PID: 1655
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vivotelecom/com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0d0000
```

Se anexa el archivo java de la actividad para tener un mayor panorama de lo que podría estar mal.

La métodos procesarPago(String amount) y onResultActivity(int, int, Intent) son conforme a la API de PayPal para procesar los pagos.

```java
public class PagoLinea extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Request PAYPAL
    private static final int PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    public  static final String PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID="Aciz1zl044BrRO9GKMA7B38BZ5mDJLGai9eGTTbp9ftgd9D4GdcGLx7f0oLWD0Pr0grY3RHGugmMzpG3";
    private static final PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration().environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX).clientId(PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID);


    ImageButton backPay, b_historial, btnPago;
    TextView t_historial, txtPago, txtPagoIva, fpago, month;
    EditText pago;
    String amount;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pago_linea);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
        startService(intent);



        txtPago = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cant_pago);
        txtPagoIva = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cant_pago_iva);
        fpago = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtFUpdate);
        month = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMes);
        pago = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPago);
        backPay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibtnBackPay);
        btnPago = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_payment);
        backPay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        t_historial = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tbtnHistorial);
        t_historial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),Historial.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        b_historial = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnHistorial);
        b_historial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),Historial.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        btnPago.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                procesarPago(pago.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        Intent intent1 = getIntent();

        String exContrato = intent1.getStringExtra("con");

        obtenerMens("http://10.0.2.2/BD_VivoSistemas/WS_DatosPago.php?num_contrato_con="+exContrato);

    }

    private void obtenerMens(String URL){
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                //Toast.makeText(PagoLinea.this, "Si entra", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        txtPagoIva.setText(jsonObject.getString("costo_mensualidad_paq"));
                        datosPago();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(PagoLinea.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(PagoLinea.this, "Error de conexión", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

    }

    private void datosPago(){
        String txPago = txtPagoIva.getText().toString();
        //Toast.makeText(this, "El texto es: "+txPago, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        double pagoSub = Double.parseDouble(txPago);
        double pagar = pagoSub*0.84;
        String pagoTot = String.valueOf(pagar);

        txtPago.setText(pagoTot);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String exFUpdate =  intent.getStringExtra("fupdate");
        fpago.setText(exFUpdate);
        String mes =  intent.getStringExtra("mes");
        month.setText(mes);

        pago.setText(txPago);
    }

    private void procesarPago(String amount){
        amount = pago.getText().toString();
        PayPalPayment payPalPayment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(amount), "MXN", "Pagado", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), PaymentActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payPalPayment);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE){
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                PaymentConfirmation confirmation = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if(confirmation != null){
                    try {
                        String paymentDetails = confirmation.toJSONObject().toString(4);
                        Log.i("paymentExample", paymentDetails);
                        startActivity(new Intent(this ,DetallePago.class).putExtra("PaymentDetails", paymentDetails).putExtra("PaymentAmount", pago.getText().toString()));
                    } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                }
            }else if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else if(resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Invalida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }



    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
        else {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    }
}
```

Y sí, ya agregué los datos de mi sandbox de Paypal para las pruebas.
Se ha actualizado la pregunta con el código completo de la actividad y la

Comment: Se agradece que pongas la traza completa del error como texto, no como imagen. Como texto es más fácil de analizar el error. Parace que hay problema con algún recurso drawable. Pon el código completo de tu Activity, pues el error no creo que esté en el código que estás mostrando actualmente. Pulsa en [edit] para actualizar la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano Se ha actualizado la pregunta, gracias.

Comment: Pon el mensaje completo de error aunque sea largo, es información valiosa. Empieza revisando si las imágenes que intentas encontrar existen en el layout y tienen los ids que indicas en tu código, me refiero a esta: `backPay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibtnBackPay);` y a las otras imágenes que tienes en tu código. Si es posible, agrega también el XML del layout a la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a el mensaje de error:

> com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity}:
> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID
> #0x7f0d0000

El problema no se presenta en `PagoLinea` , se presenta en la Activity `PaymentActivity` del SDK de Paypal.

Puedes buscar en tu proyecto el archivo R.java, abrelo y busca el id `0x7f0d0000` , te indicara cual es especificamente el recurso que falta en tu proyecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso lo solucionó correctamente.